# India: GST tax invoice received after booking a plane ticket. Do I have to pay more?

Tags: india, taxes

I booked a flight in India with Go Indigo.  I booked it online, from Canada.  A few weeks later I got an email with a tax invoice that says that the "taxable amount" is 123 Rupees.  I don't understand what this document is for.  Is it a bill that I have to pay?  If so, how?  Is it for my records for some reason?  If so...what am I supposed to do with it?  The amount isn't big at all so I'm not worried about paying it, but I am worried about *not* paying it and finding out that my ticket got cancelled because I didn't.

Comment: In a lot of countries, the term "tax invoice" is basically the same as "receipt". I am not certain about India specifically, but from what I know about other countries, you don't owe anything extra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing more to be paid. If you are a business owner in India, the tax you have already paid on this ticket, can be set off against other taxes charged on your business income.

Comment: +1 The business term is "input tax credit" and the invoice acknowledges that you have paid X amount as GST for this ticket. This is mostly for business travellers. [This article](https://www.atyourprice.net/How-to-claim-input-tax-credit-for-your-business-travel) has more details.

Comment: Thanks! Is that why they asked for a gst number when I booked? It was optional so I skipped that part

Comment: Yes, that's why they asked. Its optional. I'm a frequent flyer in India and don't mention it.